# How to get the first child from a recursive relationship

Tags: python, django

I've been using

```
def get_all_children(self, include_self=True):
    r = []
    if include_self:
        r.append(self)
    for c in Cateogory.objects.filter(parent=self):
        _r = c.get_all_children(include_self=True)
        if 0 < len(_r):
            r.extend(_r)
    return r
```

to get all the children of an object, however it returns all the children of its children as well. How can I can only the first, direct children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return all the `Category`s with as `parent` the current item with:

```
def get_direct_children(self):
    return Category.objects.filter(parent=self)
```